# converting float to integer in a special way

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to convert float number in Java to integer on the following way:

```
4.55 = 455
12.45 = 1245
11.1234 = 111234
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Convert to string, remove dot, convert to int. Mind that Integer may overflow.

Comment: Multiply by 100. Multiply by 10000.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be like this:

```
float number = 4.55f;
int desiredNumber = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(number).replaceAll("\\.", ""));
```

But something like this will only work if the conversion pattern will stay the same. By this I mean the way you want to convert from float to int. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

here is an example

```
double f1 = 4.5;

    String str = new Double(f1).toString();
    str = str.replace(".", "");

    Integer i = Integer.parseInt(str);

    System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: Mind that if the result lies outside the `int` range (up to a little over 2 000 000 000), you will get a `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to hanlde arbitrarily large numbers and arbitrarily many decimals, then you can use `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger`

```
    BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(
            "5464894984546489498454648949845464894984546489498454648949845464894984546489498454648949845464894984.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111");
    String valueOf = number.toPlainString();
    BigInteger desired = new BigInteger((valueOf.replaceAll("\\.", "")));
    System.out.println(desired);
```

Constructor can take double or float if needed

```
    BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(Float.MAX_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```
  public int convert( float numbre) {

    String nmbre = String.valueOf(numbre).replace(".", "");
             return Integer.parseInt(nmbre );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the number to a String, remove the dot, and create a new Long:

```
private long removeTheDot(Number number) {
    return Long.valueOf(number.toString().replace(".", ""));
}
```

Ka-Bam!